# Input date - Various colors inside input according to the sub value

Tags: html, css, angular, date, input

I notice that the date input works differently from the other inputs.
I would like to know if it is possible to have different colors inside the date input.

To illustrate, I would like that when nothing is written inside:
[image]

And have this when we are typing the date:

[image]

I'm developing with Angular, I have not done HTMLElement, but I can in need.

Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-pusdk7

Is it possible to get something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
 <input type="date"
    name="Birth date"
    [formControlName]="BIRTH_DATE"
  />
```

Comment: label isn't a property of input.